# Automatically creating tests in intellij idea with multiple test directories

Tags: java, testing, gradle, intellij-idea

in my project I decided to split unit and integration tests into separate packages and my project structure basically looks like this:

```
├── main
│   ├── java
│   │   └── ...
│   └── resources
│       └── ...
├── test
│   └── java
│       └── ...
└── test-integration
    ├── java
    │   └── ...
    └── resources
        └── ...
```

It is a good choice to easily separate two kinds of tests, and intellij refactoring works fine with this solution. Everything is set up correctly, both `test` directories are marked as `test sources roots` using gradle's `idea` plugin, gradle recognizes both source sets, I have two separate tasks created to run each test suite etc. The only problem I have is that intellij automatic *create test* wizard doesn't differentiate between these two directories, and the only thing I can modify is the `Destination package` classpath, which obviously is identical for both test directories, and there is no option to choose which one I'd like to use.

Is there any way to configure IDEA to give me an option to choose between directories the test will be generated in? Or maybe some kind of gradle plugin that will move test files based on their suffix (e.g. `*Test` classes go to `test` directory, and `*IT` classes go to `test-integration` directory)? Or maybe there simply is no such option :D

[image: IDEA create test wizard]

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to do that. Here's [the source](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/java/java-impl/src/com/intellij/testIntegration/createTest/CreateTestDialog.java) for that dialog. Ultimately what determines the directory is [this method](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/java/java-impl/src/com/intellij/testIntegration/createTest/CreateTestAction.java#L158):

```
protected static List<VirtualFile> computeTestRoots(@NotNull Module mainModule) {
    if (!computeSuitableTestRootUrls(mainModule).isEmpty()) {
      //create test in the same module, if the test source folder doesn't exist yet it will be created
      return suitableTestSourceFolders(mainModule)
          .map(SourceFolder::getFile)
          .filter(Objects::nonNull)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

IntelliJ is very extensible. You could write your own plugin relatively easily which changes this behaviour, by replacing the dialog associated with the action with your own dialog. Your own dialog could mostly be a copy-paste of what's already there, but with a different implementation of `selectTargetDirectory`.

Answer (score 1):

The next step after **"Create Test**" dialog should be **"Choose destination directory"**:
[image]

The behaviour in v2020.1.1 (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download).